# Load Eclipse RCP 4 default perspective programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am creating eclipse RCP 4.x application. Application consist of multiple perspectives. I want to open default perspective programmatically depending on some condition. Below code is capable of loading perspective.

```
@Execute
public void execute(MApplication app, EPartService partService,
        EModelService modelService) {
    MPerspective element = 
                (MPerspective) modelService.find("com.sanyotechnologyindia.desktop.app.perspective.enduser", app);
    // now switch perspective
    partService.switchPerspective(element);
}
```

But I can not put this code in method which is annotated with @PostContextCreate.
Can you suggest any solution for this?

================
As per solution suggested by Greg, I tried following code in Application Lifecycle class.

```
@ProcessAdditions
void processAdditions(MApplication app, EPartService partService,
        EModelService modelService){
     MPerspective element = 
                (MPerspective) modelService.find("com.sanyotechnologyindia.desktop.app.perspective.usermanagement", app);
    // now switch perspective
    partService.switchPerspective(element);
}
```

Now I am getting following error at line  partService.switchPerspective(element);

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window

================Update:==================
Added org.eclipse.osgi.services plugin to dependencies.

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextContext(IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
   eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, 
                         new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler());
}

private class AppStartupCompleteEventHandler implements EventHandler
{
    @Inject private MApplication app;
    @Inject private EPartService partService;
    @Inject private EModelService modelService;
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
        MPerspective element = 
                (MPerspective) modelService.find("com.sanyotechnologyindia.desktop.app.perspective.usermanagement", app);

    partService.switchPerspective(element);

    }
}
```

However now framework not able to inject MApplication,EPartService and EModelService in AppStartupCompleteEventHandler instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do this in your life cycle class try putting it in a `@ProcessAdditions` method rather than `@PostContextCreate`. `@ProcessAdditions` runs later in the life cycle just before the model is rendered.

Update:

Even `@PostAdditions` is too early to do some UI operations. You need to wait for the application start complete event. You can subscribe to this event using the event broker in the `@PostContextCreate` method:

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextContext(IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
   eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, 
                         new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler());
}


private class AppStartupCompleteEventHandler implements EventHandler 
{
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(final Event event)
  {
    // TODO do UI operations here
  }
}
```

`EventHandler` is `org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler`.

Update:
If you want to use injection in the event handler you must create the handler using `ContextInjectionFactory':

```
EventHandler handler = ContextInjectionFactory.make(AppStartupCompleteEventHandler.class, context);
```

where `context` is the `IEclipseContext`.

Note: You can't use this for a non-static inner class, instead use:

```
EventHandler handler = new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler();

ContextInjectionFactory.inject(handler, context);
```

This method does not support injection on the constructor.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have tried your solution and now I am getting IllegalStateException. I have updated question.Any suggestion?

Comment: @user2907714 Added app startup complete event, hopefully switch perspective will work at that point.

Comment: Hi Greg, I have updated code. This time framework is not able to inject properties into class.

Comment: If you want to use Injection you must create the object with `ContextInjectionFactory` - see updated answer